# Coincidence of triangle centres

Tags: geometry

There are a number of results in triangle geometry of the type: if two specific centres (as a concrete example, the incentre and the circumcentre) coincide, then the triangle is equilateral.  Does anybody know of a synthetic proof for the corresponding result for the centroid and the Feuerbach centre?  (for definitions, I refer to the easily accessed site "Encyclopedia of Triangle Centers").

Comment: Given that the Feuerbach center is the midpoint of the orthocenter and the circumcenter and that the centroid divides the segment from the orthocenter to the circumcenter in the ratio $2 : 1$ these four points must coincide.

Comment: @Martin Thank you for the succinct answer.  I would like to accept and upvote but don't seem to have these options,  The reason I asked this is that since there are over 5k labelled centres and so, potentially, 12 million such results.  I have developed a unified method to prove them but can't prove a general result---I have to do each one separately.  Only takes a couple of minutes in each case but with 12 million... I would be interested if anybody else has obtained a general result.

Comment: I put a version of my comment into an answer box, so that you can accept it if you wish. I am unaware of any general results in this direction, but this doesn't mean much...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Feuerbach center is the midpoint of the orthocenter and the circumcenter (see e.g. [Theorem 1.82](http://books.google.com/books?id=VdAM58ksvcIC&pg=PA21) of Coxeter-Greitzer, *[Geometry Revisited](http://books.google.com/books?id=VdAM58ksvcIC)*, page 21).

The centroid divides the segment from the orthocenter to the circumcenter in the ratio $2 : 1$.

Therefore the Feuerbach center, the centroid, the orthocenter and the circumcenter must coincide.

A triangle in which any two of circumcenter, orthocenter and centroid coincide [is equilateral](http://math.ucr.edu/~res/inprogress/concurrence2.pdf).